# Char Arrays comparison

Tags: java, arrays, char

I am trying to build something like a hangman (for beginners)

I try this:

```
int i = 0;
int fails = 0;
boolean success = false;
boolean retval;
char[] defineword = new char[] { 'h', 'u', 'n', 'g' };
char[] givenchar = new char[0];
char[] testchar = new char[] { 'h' };

while (success == false && fails < 5) {
    System.out.println("Give a char: ");
    String word = input.next(); // INPUT STRING
    givenchar = word.toCharArray(); // CONVERT

    retval = Arrays.equals(givenchar, testchar);
    System.out.println("THE LETTER IS " + retval);
    if (retval == true) {
        testchar[0] = defineword[i + 1];
    } else {
        fails++;
    }
}
```

The problem is that it can't continue after the letter ('u'), it is stuck in 'u'.

Comment: 1) There is no need to add the major tag in the title. 2) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: There's a whole lot wrong with your code so there's no one simple answer.

Answer (score 0):

One observation I will make is that you only real comparison is between `givenchar`, and `testchar`.

```
retval = Arrays.equals(givenchar, testchar);
```

It would make sense that this wouldn't work once you got past `u` because `testchar` never gets past `u` either.  I think you might have intended to add an `i++` somewhere.

```
testchar[0] = defineword[i + 1];
```

Comment: @Vulcan, and the problem here is that `i` is not updated to reflect the new state.

Answer (score 0):

```
package mer;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Aswe
{
 int i=0;
 int f=0;
 boolean suc=false;
 boolean ret;
 char[] dw=new char[]{'h','u','n','g'};
 char[] gc=new char[0];
 char[] tc=new char[]{'h'};
 Scanner i1;
 public void me()
  {
   i1=new Scanner(System.in);
   while(suc==false&&f<5)
    {
      System.out.println("give a char");
      String ch=i1.nextLine();

      gc=ch.toCharArray();

      ret=eual(gc,tc);
      System.out.println("the letter is"+ret);

      if(ret)
       {
         tc[0]=dw[i+1];
       }
     else
      f++;
 }
}
public boolean eual(char[] a,char[] b)
{
   if(a[0]==b[0])
    return true;
   else
    return false;
}
  public static void main(String ... args)
 {
   new Aswe().me();
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private int fails = 0;
private final int maxFails = 5;

private char[] answer = new char[] {'j','a','v','a'};

public Hangman() {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    /*
     * Game Loop
     */
    while(fails < maxFails){
        System.out.print("Enter a char: ");
        char givenChar = scan.next().charAt(0);
        System.out.println("Given char is: " + Check(answer,givenChar));
    }
}

/*
 * Check if the char exists in the array.
 */
private boolean Check(char[] array,char value){

    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        if(array[i] == value){
            return true;
        }
    }

    /*
     * Okay did not find any char that match return false.
     */
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I would recommend using object oriented programming.